# Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. want to increment constant varible in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want count varible to count how many norms voilated in my app. so i have declared variable `normsCount: 0` in state.
in function checking norms like below and increment count.

```
const {
normsCount
        } = this.state

if (isViolationPass_Out_HMR) {
            this.setState({
                normsCount: normsCount + 1
            })
        }
```

but getting this error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:180 Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:412)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
```

any help thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković just simple like this renderCarrierEngineHMR() {}

Comment: That's function declaration, not a function call

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković this.renderCarrierEngineHMR()

Comment: But where are you calling it... You need to show all the relevant code

Comment: Add your full code, usage along with declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you set a state in your render-function the state will be changed which causes a re-render. That is causing the infinite loop.

You need to make sure that the increase is only triggered on the change once.

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: I have no idea of the logic behind your function, you can have another state variable that checks if the increase has been done or you change the place where this change of state is done, not in render, but in an event handler, etc. Maybe a `console.log(this.state.normsCount)` will help you to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setState inside the function which is getting called inside the render function, which is calling setState continuously causing infinite loop. To stop this, you will have to do setState on any event like onclick. Check for the setState which is getting called inside the render function and  do that setState on an event.